# Binding to a Rectangle within a ListBox ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListBox, which uses data binding for content (bound to an ObservableCollection), and an ItemTemplate for layout. Within the ItemTemplate, there is a TextBlock displaying a date (from the ObservableCollection), and a colored Rectangle.

I want the rectangle's fill color to change based on the date (to indicate age). However, since the Rectangle itself isn't bound to the date (and I don't see how it could be), I haven't been able to get a DataTrigger to work to alter the fill color.

Is there another way to get the Rectangle color to be controlled by the data binding?

**Edit:**

Here is a (simplified) copy of my ListBox ItemTemplate, as requested. Right now, the Rectangle's fill is a set color, but I want to change it to vary based on the targetstartdate field.

```cs
<ListBox Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=testList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Rectangle Fill="#FF009A00" Width="5" StrokeThickness="1" Margin="0,1,4,1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding targetstartdate}" Margin="0,0,0,4" Foreground="#FF009A00" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: You don't need any `Converter`... you can just use a `DataTrigger`. Add your `DataTemplate` and I'll show you.

Comment: McCarnagle pretty much laid it out for you. All you need to do is define your converter logic in the Convert method and then bind it, so where he put Stroke="{Binding Date ... in the first code fragment, substitute it with Stroke="{Binding targetstartdate since that is the actual name of your var.

Comment: Looking into it, I take it back... it doesn't look like you *can* do this with a `DataTrigger`. At first I thought that you just wanted certain dates to change the colour, but looking into it, it turns out to be far more complicated than I first thought. Even if it were possible though, and you want to have different colours for different date ranges, then you'd need to use the `Converter` method anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the rectangle's `Fill` or `Stroke` property to the Date.  Then, use an [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to convert the date to the appropriate color.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:DateToBrushConverter x:Key="DateToBrushConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<Rectangle Fill="{Binding targetstartdate,Converter={StaticResource DateToBrushConverter}}" 
... />
```

The `Convert` method should return a `Brush` object, which matches the `Rectangle.Fill` property.

```
public class DateToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var date = value as DateTime?;
        if (!date.HasValue)
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        else if (!date.Value > DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1))
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        // etc
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind rectangle's color to an IValueConverter, use the date as binding and determine the color based on the date inside the IValueConverter class.